# import sys error in pycharm 2.5.1

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm a newbie using python and ubuntu, and I'm trying to `import sys` to my code , but it always gave me an error with the element that is using `sys`:

```
import sys
Q = sys.argv[1]
```

the error came with every statement that is using the sys, even when I comment the one that has the error, the one after it then will have an error ...

```
Q = sys.argv[1]
```

the error:

```
"IndexError: list index out of range"
```

Q: Is there anyway to import `sys` to the `pycharm` ??

Q: What are the prerequisite of it?

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with the `import`. `sys.argv[1]` is the first argument provided to the Python script.

So if you do (for example)

```
C:\Python27> python.exe myscript.py Hello!
```

then `sys.argv` is `["myscript.py", "Hello!"]`, so `sys.argv[1]` is `"Hello!"`.

If you don't provide an argument, then `sys.argv` will just be `["myscript.py"]` - consequently, you can't access `sys.argv[1]` because it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You have imported `sys` correctly. The error occurs when tying to access `sys.argv[1]`, which is an argument you pass to the `python` executable.

If you just run `python scriptname.py`, without any other arguments, there is no `sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: as what I understood, if I don't have commands , then I can't use import sys??

Comment: You can always `import sys`, but you can't do access `sys.argv[1]` if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to run your code in the terminal (Mac, Linux, or Unix) or the command prompt (Windows) as mentioned in the answer above by Tim, but for Linux/Unix/Mac you take out the .exe from python as follows: `python myscript.py Hello`

If you still want to do something similar in PyCharm, you have to pass the arguments as follows:

1. From the menu bar on the top, click on **Run**
2. Then click on **Edit Configurations..**
3. A dialog box will open, and then enter your arguments inside the **Script Parameters** field
4. Click **Ok** or **Apply**
5. Then run, or debug your code and it will run!